# i want to parse the json file only if it matches to the specified structure in python

Tags: python, json

The structure of the json file has to be specified in the python program. the program should parse any input json file only if it matches to that structure. I'm new to python please help me!

sample json file may be like this

```
"person":{
"sex":{
"name": "XXX",
"address":[
    {
        "street": "abc",
        "area"  : "xyz",
       },
     ],
  }
```

the json files having this structure only has to be parsed, if there is one extra field other than these shouldn't be parsed.
Please help me out Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, just parse the file with the json module, then control that the structure is what you expect. Where is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

With these two functions you can check all keys in your dictionaries
if the keys are equal it will return True

```
def get_keys(obj, keys=[]):
    ''' creates a list with all keys from a nested, json valid dictionary '''
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list) and all(isinstance(item,dict) for item in v):

                keys.append(k)
                return get_keys(v, keys)
            else:
                keys.append(k)
        #calls get_keys with the list of keys as object this will trigger the else statement and return the object
        else: return get_keys(keys)

    elif isinstance(obj, list) and all(isinstance(item, dict) for item in obj):
        #checks if obj is a list and if all obj in a list are dictionaries
        for dct in obj:
            for k, v in dct.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list) and isinstance(v[0], dict):

                    keys.append(k)
                    return get_keys(v, keys)
                else:
                    keys.append(k)
            #same as above
            else: return get_keys(keys)
    else:
        return obj

def has_same_structure(dct_1,dct_2):
    ''' checks if two (nested) dictionaries have the same keys '''
    if get_keys(dct_1) == get_keys(dct_2, keys=[]):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I hope this helps